# Looking for losiless video encoding

Tags: video, codec, steganography

I am working on video steganography and the process is as follows.

a) On the Sender's side, decompose the video into frames(images).

b) Hide secret data into some of the frames.

c) Encode the frames into video and send the video to the receiver.

d) On the receiver's side, decode and decompose the video into frames
   and extract the secret data hidden in the frames.

My problem is when I encode the video after inserting secret data, the
codec changes the frames and therefore, I lose track of my hidden data
and/or the hidden data(message) may change.

Please suggest a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hiding secret data in the frames itself, then to do this without impacting the quality of the video is not trivial and there are technologies that are focused on doing just this. This is how video watermarking typically  works.

There are open source image steganography libraries which would be a good place to start, for example (you likely know it, but just in case...): https://github.com/syvaidya/openstego